# Помогите пожалуйста дорешать задачу

Tags: c++, массивы

> Нужно вывести все положительные числа, если количество четных элементов в массиве больше, иначе вывести все отрицательные элементы.

Я реализовал задачу в другом коде, но здесь обязательно нужно весь код "растащить" по функциям, с функциями  пока не работал, поэтому очень тяжело дается. Составил мысленно план действий, но реализовать не могу

1. Создать массив.
2. Найти количество четных элементов и записать их в другой массив.
3. Аналогично с нечетными.
4. Сравнить массив четных и нечетных чисел.
5. Если массив четных больше, то выводятся положительные элементы исходного, и наоборот.
   Как видно, дальше первого не ушел. Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
 int* create_array(int size)
 {
          int*x = new int[size];
          int A = -100;
          int B = 100;
          for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
          {
               *(x+i) = rand() % 101-50;
          }
                return x;
 }
 void print_positive_array(int* &x, int size)
   {
         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) // N - кол - во элементов массива
         { 
       
            if (x[i] > 0)
             cout << "Положительное число : " << x[i] << endl;

          }       
    }
    
 void print_negative_array(int* &x, int size)
   {
         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) // N - кол - во элементов массива
         { 
       
            if (x[i] < 0)
             cout << "Отрицательное число : " << x[i] << endl;

          }     
    }
 void print_array(int* arr, int size)
   {
         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         {
         cout << *(arr+i) << " ";
         }
         cout << endl;
    }

 void chetnost(int* &x, int* &y, int size)
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
          if ((x[i] %2 ==0)>(x[i] %2 !=0))
          {
              y[i]=x[i];
          }
      }
 }


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    cout << "Если количество нечетных больше четных, то вывести отрицательные элементы. Иначе положительные" << endl;
    int n, size;
    cout << "Введите размер массивов" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int *x = new int[n];
    int *b = new int[n];
    int *y = new int[n];
    srand(time(0));
    x = create_array(n);
    print_array(x, n);
    chetnost(x, y, n);
    cout << endl << endl;

    print_array(y, n);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

зачем так сложно?

1. пройти по массиву и подсчитать кол-во четных элементов в массиве и кол-во нечетных элементов

это можно выполнить за один проход, т.е. будет что-то типа такого:

```
int even = 0;
int odd = 0;

...

if (arr[index] % 2 == 1)
    odd ++;
else
    even ++;
```

2. в зависимости от того каких элементов больше - вывести только положительные или отрицательные

это выполняется за еще один проход массива

```
if (odd > even)
{
    if (arr[index] < 0)
        std::cout << arr[index] << " ";
}
else
{
    if (arr[index] > 0)
        std::cout << arr[index] << " ";
}
```

и все - не надо делать лишних телодвижений, разрывать массив на два и т.д.

все делается в 2 этапа - считаем четные и нечетные, потом зная что именно нам надо вывести - выводим

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение, скажите пожалуйста как представить это в виде функций?

Comment: вам обязательно это в виде нескольких функций нужно сделать? зачем? ну создайте первую функцию, которая определит надо выводить отрицательные или положительные числа типа `bool isPositive(const int* array, const int size){... return even > odd;}`, а потом вторую функцию которая выводит числа `void showNumbers(const int* array, const int size, const bool isEnabledPositive){...}` ну или для вывода сделать две функции `showPositive(const int* array, const int size){...}`, `showNegative(const int* array, const int size){...}`, а какую вызвать - определять по результату функции `isPositive`

Comment: Да, обязательно в виде функций. Зачем? Честно говоря, не знаю. Спасибо, попробую так

Comment: И все таки я не понимаю как разделить это на функции, да и что писать там вообще.

Comment: Давайте для начала обойдемся без функций, на функции всегда разодрать можно потом. Вы можете написать первую часть - у вас есть массив, надо подсчитать кол-во четных и нечетных чисел за один `for`?

Comment: Наверное да, сейчас попробую.

Comment: сделайте, выведите на экран, проверьте руками что правильно. Если все хорошо будет, тогда написать 2 кода - вывести все положительные и вывести все отрицательные числа - тоже проверить

Comment: Вообще никак не получается, я не могу

Comment: ну покажите что получается хотя бы - что именно не получается, почему не можете, что именно не понимаете?

Comment: А каким образом я могу показать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117655/discussion-between-zhihar-and-zhenyadze).

Comment: Ну помогите пожалуйста функции написать

Comment: я же вам все в чате дал - или вы скажите прямо не "ПОМОГИТЕ ДОРЕШАТЬ", а "РЕШИТЕ ВМЕСТО МЕНЯ", где у вас сложности в этот раз возникли то?

Comment: Все там же, не могу представить функции

Comment: я вам сказал - 1) разбить свою задачу на логически независимые блоки 2) написать алгоритм (хотя бы на бумаге) 3) закодить. Вы уперлись в функции - это задача решается в 5 строчек без функций - решите ее пока БЕЗ функций, а потом занести функционал в функции легко будет. Напишите свой алгоритм в виде этапов текстом "на бумаге" и приведите здесь

Comment: Простите, это опять я. Прошу Вас, помогите. Срочно нужно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117708/discussion-between-zhihar-and-zhenyadze).